# How to display data in a graphic bar from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, charts

I am trying to display some data in a graphic bar using javascript for a selected period.
So i want to select a date range to display data to graphic bar e.x: if (user:John) on date:13.feb.2014 from time: 14:00-1530 have performed a duty and in same date from time: 18:00-20:00 to display in a graphical bar, so basicalli display all the dutis of (user:John) in the same row for the period i previously select.
e.x: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/floating-bar-chart/#theme-none

Any suggestion on how can i obtain this result?

Comment: You would look at how that library formats the data in HTML/Javascript and write your PHP code to return the data from the database in that way, and use that library.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link: http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/.
It uses jQuery and Raphael libraries and the result is very nice. I use it often.